# Xamrin Button is not working for mmvm-light Relay Command

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light, relaycommand

In my Xamrin forms code i have configured MVVM light
RelayCommand is not hitting even though I have set the property in xaml page for the command.

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ContentPage BackgroundColor="White" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ContractorActionSolution.CSA.CSAContentPages.Demo">
<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
        <OnPlatform.iOS>0,20,0,0</OnPlatform.iOS>
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Padding>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Image x:Name="imgLogo" Source="sisystems_logo.jpg" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label x:Name="lblmsg" TextColor="#F25B63" Text="Error Message"/>
            <Entry x:Name="txtUserName" Placeholder="Email"/>
            <Entry x:Name="txtPassword" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"/>
            <Button  Command="{Binding IncrementCommand}" Text="Continue"/>
            <Label Text="Can't Login ?" TextColor="#F25B63" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Code**

```
public partial class Demo : ContentPage
{      
    DemoViewModel _myViewModel;
    public Demo ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();           
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        BindingContext = App.Locator.DemoVM;
        _myViewModel = BindingContext as DemoViewModel;
    }
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        _myViewModel.CleanUP();
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class DemoViewModel : BaseViewModel
{      
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { Set(() => Name, ref _name, value); }
    }

    private RelayCommand _incrementCommand;
    /// <summary>  
    /// Gets the IncrementCommand.  
    /// </summary>  
    public RelayCommand IncrementCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _incrementCommand ?? (_incrementCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {                        
                }));
        }
    }
    public void CleanUP()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
    }        
}
```

I have also tried using `RelayCommand` and `RelayAsyncCommand` both are not working.

Property bindings are working fine,

I can add binding for entry with a `string` property, but not able to add `RelayCommand` with a button.

Comment: Have you tried to add something in the command handler? At first glance everything seems to be ok

Comment: no i didnt add command handler @MartinZikmund

Comment: Try to add some code inside (like `Debug.WriteLine("test")`) and put a breakpoint there to see if it is triggered when the button is clicked.

Comment: It working fine ! i came to know my issue it was an empty command

Comment: I have written an answer with my suggestion, please consider accepting it so that the question is resolved :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be the fact that the handler is empty and optimization actually omits it after compilation. Try to add anything inside, like `Debug.WriteLine("Test");` to see if the breakpoint is hit then.